# Excel マクロでDeepLを用いて翻訳する際、英文をピリオド区切りではなくセル内の丸ごとで翻訳したい

Tags: vba, 自然言語処理

表題の通りですが、文章がピリオド区切り、つまり一つの文のみでDeepLに入力されてしまうので、英文全体をセルから取得したいです。.Valueの箇所を.Textに変更したりはしています。

```
Sub Translate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim Sh_1 As Worksheet
    Set Sh_1 = Worksheets("###########")
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    Dim lastRow_1 As Long
    lastRow_1 = Sh_1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim loop_1 As Long
    Dim S_english As String
    Dim S_wayaku As String

    For loop_1 = 3 To lastRow_1
        S_english = Sh_1.Cells(loop_1, 3).Value
        ie.navigate "https://www.deepl.com/ja/translator#en/ja/" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(S_english)

        Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Do
            S_wayaku = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("lmt__target_textarea")(0).innerText
        Loop Until S_wayaku <> ""
        Sh_1.Cells(loop_1, 4).Value = S_wayaku
        Debug.Print loop_1
    Next

    ie.Quit 'ie終了
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox ("wd")

End Sub
```

Comment: こちらの記事 [VBA_1001 英文一括翻訳マクロ (English Translation Batch Macro)](http://blog.livedoor.jp/account_program/archives/8215277.html) のプログラムを元にしているようですが。別にプログラムを変更しなくても、Excelデータの方をあらかじめ1つのセルにまとめておけば良いのでは？

Comment: @kunif はい、そうです。文章を行と列番号が対応しているセルとして区切っているので、まとめるのは難しそうですね。英文自体の構文解析を工夫すればよいかも知れませんが（短文のみでマクロをかけて長文はExcelから手作業など）、基本的には、セルの文章をまるごとDEEPLに入れるマクロの文字列操作処理を知りたいです。

Comment: プログラムでやりたいなら、これ [【エクセルVBA】複数セルの文字列を連結合！CONCAT関数の使い方！VBAへの組み込みまで](https://www.higashisalary.com/entry/excel-concat) でセルの範囲を指定すれば出来るでしょう。

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございます。ただ、"/","."などで文字列が区切られて値が取得されてしまい、一まとまとりの文章として翻訳したいという事です。

Comment: ご質問を拝読して、例えばC3セルに"This is a dog. That is a cat."と書かれていた場合、なぜか"This is a dog."のみがDeepLに入力されてしまうという質問かと思ったのですがそれは誤読でしょうか？(ちなみに手元のOffice365環境でご質問のコードを実行したところ、ピリオドや改行も含めてセル全体を入力、翻訳できています)

Comment: @payaneco そうです。まさしく仰る通りです。バックスラッシュも区切り文字になります。上記コードママで問題ないのであれば、もう一台のffice３６５のPCがあるのでそちらでもトライしてもよいかなと思います。

Comment: サンプルとして具体的なセルの内容も質問に含めた方が良さそうです。

Comment: @cubick、@payaneco,@kunif　さん、皆様ご丁寧にありがとうございます。恒例の、"/" や”（）”,"#"を処理する際に問題があり、そこを修正すれば文章を翻訳出来ました。英文において、当該記号を内容により適当な接続詞などに変更したいと思います。結論としては、原文でマクロが読み込めなさそうな部分などを"This is a dog. That is a cat."レベルの単純な文章に修正する必要があったという事です。もしかしたら自然言語処理に括られる内容かも知れません。

Answer (score 1):

> S_english = Sh_1.Cells(loop_1, 3).Value

の表現では、"/" や"（）","#"を処理する際に問題があり、そこを修正すれば文章丸ごとを翻訳出来ました。（つまり、当該記号が処理する最後の部分となりますこの場合はDeepLに送る値）

英文において、当該記号を内容に応じて適当な接続詞に変更するなどすれば（"/" ⇒ or/andなどに適宜）、問題なくセル内の文章丸ごとを翻訳する事が出来るかと思います。